# Android PinnedHeaderListView headers not pinning

Tags: java, android, adt, android-source

Hi i am trying to use the `PinnedHeaderListView` class to get a list view with headers, just like the `contacts app` in Android.

The headers display fine, however, they do not pin to the top when scrolling, like in the contacts app. instead they just scroll past like normal `listview` items.

How can i fix this?

Here's a snippet of my fragment and adapter classes:

```
public class StaffSectionFragment extends ListFragment implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
private ListFragment mFragment;
private StaffListAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Staff> staffList;

public StaffSectionFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the view from fragment_courses.xml
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_staff);

    adapter = new StaffListAdapter();
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_staff, null);

    PinnedHeaderListView listview =(PinnedHeaderListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pinnedListView);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}


private void setupListView()
{

}

public class StaffListAdapter extends SectionedBaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int section, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int section, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionCount() {
        //*************DO THIS*****************
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCountForSection(int section) {
        //*************DO THIS*****************
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(int section, int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinearLayout layout = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        else
        {
            layout = (LinearLayout)convertView;
        }
        //set item
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listtextItem)).setText("Section " + section + " item " + position);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout layout = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.header_item, null);
        }
        else
        {
            layout = (LinearLayout)convertView;
        }
        //set item
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.headertextItem)).setText("Header for section " + section);
        return layout;
    }       
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something with the data

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mFragment = new StaffSectionFragment();
    // Attach fragment_courses.xml layout
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
    ft.attach(mFragment);

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Remove fragment_courses.xml layout
    ft.remove(mFragment);

}

}
```

Can anyone help me fix this? thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine. I'm using the same code but mine is working. The only different is I'm using Fragment instead of ListFragment. Maybe thats the reason. You need to have PinnedHeaderListView as ur listview in your layout. Can you put your layout here as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter should look like this , How many section do have ? this implementation is for one section if you have 2 or more let me know , because you should override other methods.

```
        @Override
        public Object getItem (int section, int position)
        {
             if(staffList != null ){
               if(section == 0){
                  if(position < staffList.size()){
                       return staffList.get(position);
                   } else {
                       return // do your second section header
                    }
                 }
            }
            return null;
         }  

         @Override
         public long getItemId(int section, int position) {
          return position;
        }


        @Override
        public int getSectionCount() {
        return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCountForSection(int section) {
             if (staffList != null) {
                  if(section == 0) {
             return staffList.size();
         } else {
             return // your second section
            }
             }
          return 0;
      }

      @Override 
      public  int getItemViewType(int section, int position) {

        if (section == 0 && staffList != null && position == staffList.size() + 1) {
            return 1;
        } else if (//do your second section ) {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
     }

    @Override
    public int getSectionHeaderViewType(int section) {
    return section;
   }

    @Override
    public int getSectionHeaderViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! yes I have more than 2 sections. what methods do i need to override?

Comment: check edited , then in your getItemView just specified which layout you  want to inflate for each section.Hope that's helped